# Logging into Stack Exchange doesn't log me into my existing Stack Overflow account, it keeps asking me to create a new account even though I have one?

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

From long ago I have a Stack Exchange account with two site accounts: One for Stack Overflow and one for Software Engineering. Recently, after not using any of these accounts for years, I got a notification about a new reply to a post of mine on Stack Overflow.

[image: My Stack Exchange account with accounts for Stack Overflow and Software Engineering, and a notification yesterday about a new reply to my post on Stack Overflow.]

However, when I click the notification that takes me to the reply on my own post, it doesn't let me reply, and shows "Join this community" in the corner, indicating I'm not logged in.

[image: Stack Overflow page won't acknowledge I already have a Stack Overflow account and only has a button to create a new account.]

If I click "Join this community" I'm taken to a "Confirm new account" dialog that says it'll create a new Stack Overflow for my Stack Exchange account, even though my Stack Exchange account (as shown in the first image) clearly shows that I already have a Stack Overflow account.

[image: Forced into dialog to confirm new account even though I'm logged into a Stack Exchange account that already has a Stack Overflow account.]

How can I log into my already existing Stack Overflow account instead of creating a second (???) Stack Overflow account for my Stack Exchange account which already has one? What is going on here?

Comment: Click on [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and select Account Issue (or Other if none of the options fit).

Comment: Assuming you still have your password or other credentials which you would have normally used to log into your account, I'd try clearing your browser's cookies for stackoverflow.com and then load [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), rather than following a link from your account on stackexchange.com. Hopefully, that will result in you seeing the "Log in" and "Sign up" buttons at the top of the page. You can then click on "Log in" and log in to the site using your current account.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, this worked!